# Why is there a difference between ephem positions and lookup table positions for moon

Tags: coordinates, azimuth, pyephem

I am trying to locate the moon positons (Altitude and Azimuth) using python's ephem module and comparing it to a lookup table for apparent moon positions for my location. I am noticing a significant difference in the values that i obtain for the angles. Here is my test code.

```
>>> o = ephem.Observer()
>>> o.lat = 39.2545
>>> o.lon = -76.7095
>>> o.elevation = 80
>>> o.date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> print o.date
2012/8/13 21:00:55
>>> m = ephem.Moon(o)
>>> import math
>>> azimuth = math.degrees(m.az)
>>> azimuth
286.2894281178355
>>> alt = math.degrees(m.alt)
>>> alt
19.35235063580148
```

Now, compare these angles to the lookup table values:

```
       Date/Time             Zenith         Azimuth
2012 Aug 13 21:00:00.0      88.45125       294.56966
2012 Aug 13 21:20:00.0      91.82583       297.59090
```

Note: Alt = 90 - Zenith. So our zenith value would be: 70.64764

My question is, why is there a difference? The lookup table gives the **apparent** angles. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: What lookup table are you using? Is it trustworthy? For what observer location?

Comment: the look-up table is from the Naval Observatory MICA data base and is supposed to be very good. The location is the same as the location in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accidentally offering the `lat` and `lon` values in radians, because when PyEphem is given a floating-point number it always assumes that you are doing “raw math” and submitting values in radians:

```
>>> o.lat = 39.2545
>>> o.lon = -76.7095
```

If you instead want to provide degrees and have PyEphem translate, you can either provide strings:

```
>>> o.lat = '39.2545'
>>> o.lon = '-76.7095'
```

Or you can provide numbers that you compute using a `math` function, if that helps you keep everything straight, since the PyEphem practice of converting strings to numbers is not a standard Python idiom, whereas everyone will understand `math.radians()` when reading your code:

```
>>> o.lat = math.radians(39.2545)
>>> o.lon = math.radians(-76.7095)
```

The observer that you were actually asking about with those large radian values was at the location 89:07:01.8° N, 284:52:09.8° E which is extremely near the North Pole.

Comment: Quick question: Is there a way to convert ra/dec into xyz in ephem for moon?